# Responsive layout with different arrangement

Tags: html, css, layout

I have question, how I can create layout which, which column set differently for different screen sizes

I have example:

http://jarock.pl/rock/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag-lets-play/

When you change size for small left column will move down.

Comment: what u actually need????? Responsive website.. Check for Bootstrap CSS and Do it...

Comment: I know bootstrap, but I want know to how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { ... }
```